# Failing to get a working installation of CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to use CodeIgniter following their docs, but my installation is not even working for the [first example](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html)

What I've done:

1. Download CodeIgniter and extract the files
2. Move them to `/srv/www/htdocs/ci/` (Using OpenSUSE)
3. Edit `application/config/config.php` --> `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/';`
4. Perform every step of the above linked example up to the first line in "Routing", where I need to visit `http://localhost/ci/index.php/pages/view` for testing it's working. However, I get a 404. If I go to `localhost/ci/index.php`, I can download the index.php file.

Tried to set `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php?';` as seen at other question but to no avail.

What else I'm missing?

**edit**

ok, it's something about OpenSUSE. Just tried the same steps in a Kali VM, and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me... I forgot to enable `mod_php`. Didn't know OpenSUSE doesn't do it automatically...